# How do you find the best and worst case from a pseudo code?

Tags: algorithm

I was wondering how would I find the **best**, **worst** case of this algorithm:

```
Inputs 
  A: Array of Integers; N: Integer
Variables 
  i, k: Integer
Begin
  for i := N - 2 down to 0 do
    for k := 0 to i do
      if (A[k] > A[k + 1]) then
        swap(A, k, k + 1)
      fi
    od
  od
End
```

Comment: Best case as well as worst case have `O(N**2)` time complexity; the code is a *Bubble sort* implementation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

Answer (score 0):

The worst case is when A is sorted in decreasing order. In that case the "if" statement is executed in every iteration of the nested "for".